# userform with textboxes and dates to show timeline

Tags: beginner, vba, excel

I am writing the following VBA code to make a timeline, which I will be using for other parts of the code later on for other calculations and output. I have a userform where the following number of text boxes and labels are present:

- wkbox* and intbox* are textboxes which have weeks as input from user. wkbox* is duration of a stage, intbox* is interval between two stages.
- date* are labels which give output as dates when each stage starts.
- mpsd is the input date for the entire timeline start date from mpsd.text box, which is considered as the start date in my code below

```vb
Public mpsd as date    
Private Sub Setbutton_Click()
        
    Me.date1 = mpsd
    Me.date2 = DateAdd("d", ((wkbox1 * 5) + (intbox1 * 5)), date1)
    Me.date3 = DateAdd("d", ((wkbox2 * 5) + (intbox2 * 5)), date2)
    Me.date4 = DateAdd("d", ((wkbox3 * 5) + (intbox3 * 5)), date3)
    Me.date5 = DateAdd("d", ((wkbox4 * 5) + (intbox4 * 5)), date4)
    Me.date6 = DateAdd("d", ((wkbox5 * 5) + (intbox5 * 5)), date5)
    Me.date7 = DateAdd("d", ((wkbox6 * 5) + (intbox6 * 5)), date6)
    Me.date8 = DateAdd("d", ((wkbox7 * 5) + (intbox7 * 5)), date7)
    Me.date9 = DateAdd("d", ((wkbox8 * 5) + (intbox8 * 5)), date8)
    Me.date10 = DateAdd("d", ((wkbox9 * 5) + (intbox9 * 5)), date9)
    Me.date11 = DateAdd("d", ((wkbox10 * 5) + (intbox10 * 5)), date10)
    Me.date12 = DateAdd("d", ((wkbox11 * 5) + (intbox11 * 5)), date11)
        
End sub
```

I was trying to think if there is a way to optimise this code through `for`,`case`, etc.

I am very new to VBA, so am not able to think how I can reduce this to a maybe 3 line `for` or `case` code to speed up the running of the code.

(This is just a part of a big schedule planner code, so any sec saved is good for me.)
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What's annoying my eyes first is having member variables like `Me.date1` to `Me.dateN`, which should be rather replaced with an array `Me.dates[N]` and and a properly indexing loop to call `DateAdd()`.

Comment: Thank you for your input, @πάντα ῥεῖ. However, I dont understand date1 to dateN are actual labels on my userform. I am unable to replace them with an array. It gives me a compile error. Sorry, I am very new to userform part of VBA :)

Comment: my code runs properly. It is quite simple, input is start date and weeks for each stage from the user. Output is start date for each stage. I only wanted to simplify it, if possible.
As you said. the N lines of date1 to dateN is annoying to read.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/289382/revisions#rev-body-29d89a1d-0b12-4e8a-9035-43cc0116dcac) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: Sam and I voted to reopen in unison. If you disagree you can reach out to me.